# Why is $|x|<2$ a conjunction ($x<2$ AND $-x<2$) while $|x|>2$ is a disjunction ($x>2$ OR $-x>2$)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, absolute-value

My question is regarding $|x|<2$ vs $|x|>2$. When solving the first, we have that $$x<2 \quad \mathbf{and}\quad-x<2$$ while when we solve the second we have $$x>2 \quad\mathbf{or}\quad -x>2$$

My question is

> Why is the first one a conjunction whereas the second is a disjunction? What is the logic behind that?

I am assuming it has something to do with the definition of the absolute value.

Comment: Can you visualize these inequalities on the number line? Which values of $x$ satisfy $|x|<2$? Which values of $x$ satisfy $|x|>2$?

Comment: I'm kinda playing the wild card here, but I'll say it's because we made the arbitrary choice that $|x|$ is the positive one of $x$ and $-x$. I look forward to people explaining to me why that choice is in fact not arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from DeMorgan's laws applied to the other inequality:
$$|x|>2 \iff \textrm{not }(|x|\leq 2)\tag{trichotomy}$$
$$\iff \textrm{not }(x\leq 2 \textrm{ and } -x \leq 2)\tag{other inequality}$$
$$\iff (\textrm{not }x\leq 2) \textrm{ or }(\textrm{not }-x \leq 2)\tag{DeMorgan}$$
$$\iff (x>2)\textrm{ or }(-x > 2)\tag{trichotomy}$$

Comment: Oooooh I like this answer a lot. The only unfortunate thing is how would one explain this to a high-school class that has no idea what demorgans is?

Comment: You can explain DeMorgan as $(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$ in a Venn diagram. It should be obvious.

Comment: Also how did you know that $|x|\leqslant 2$ implies $$x\leqslant 2\land -x\leqslant 2$$ and not $$x\leqslant 2 \lor -x\leqslant 2$$?

Comment: I didn't, that was assumed. I only showed that **if you know** the rule for "$<$", **then you can deduce** the rule for "$>$". Showing the first rule is a different problem, but not too hard. You can show it by realizing that $|x|$ is the distance between $x$ and $0$. All the points that are no further than $2$ units from $0$ lie between $-2$ and $2$, that is, to the right of $-2$ ($x > -2$, which is the same as $-x < 2$) and also to the left of $2$ ($x < 2$) -- so you get $|x|<2$ is equivalent to "$x<2$ and $-x<2$"

Comment: Note also I should technically prove that the rule for $\leq$ looks like the rule for $<$, and it then follows that the rule for $\geq$ looks like the rule for $>$. To do that, just realize that "$|x|\leq 2$" means "$(|x|<2)\textrm{ or }(|x| = 2)$" and work with that. It's a little messy but doable.

Comment: In the end, all of this is really a good exercise in manipulating logical statements and practicing symbolic logic. That's at the heart of mathematics and shouldn't be taken for granted. Mathematical skill in proofs rests completely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Each of those cases is really two cases:

$|x|>2$ is the same as the union of $x<0\land-x>2$ and $x\geq 0\land x>2$.  This simplifies to $x<-2\cup 2<x$.

$|x|<2$ is the same as the union of $x<0\land-x<2$ and $x>0\land x<2$.  This simplifies to $-2<x<0\cup0\leq x< 2$.  However, as the two domains are consecutive, their union can be simplified into a single domain $-2<x<2$

Comment: Oh nice yes and "$x<0\land -x<2$" comes from the definition of the absolute value yes?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Since $|x|\geq 0$, we can square both sides to obtain:

\begin{align*}
|x| < 2 & \Longleftrightarrow |x|^{2} < 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - 4 < 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - 2)(x + 2) < 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\in(-2,2).
\end{align*}

Based on such case, can you handle the other inequality?